# Migrating a Character Based Oracle Form

Tags: linux, oracle, migration

I have an OLD server running DG/UX that will in the near future be unsupported. I have some character based oracle forms that need to be migrated off of this machine. Does anyone know what sort of migration strategy Oralce has for upgrading these Character Based reports. It doesnt have to be the newest version, it doesnt even have to be to a GUI version, but I do need to migrate to a supported OS such as linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy answer is to tell you to check out [Migration from 6i to 10g](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/reports/migration/index.html).

Having done it before, what I think the much more useful answer is to tell you to rewrite those forms and reports from scratch. Probably in another tool - especially if you want to have a web interface, etc. rather than being hobbled by an ancient Java runtime.

There are products out there that will let you translate the old forms code into PL/SQL. [Kumaran](http://www.kumaran.com/ProductsOracle.html) is an example of one, but I found it buggy and had to do a lot of hand editing of the code to get it work the same as the original.

As far as I'm concerned, the CUI is dead so you might as well go all the way to a GUI. The last time I was looking at it, there was almost no documentation for CUI forms and frequently things that worked in the GUI wouldn't work in the CUI at all.

There are some problems you may run into in converting CUI based forms applications to GUI.

- Sometimes there is validation and special processing done when the user moves to the next or previous field/block/etc. When you switch over to a proper GUI, your user can skip those events by just clicking on another field. So you are left with two choices - #1 audit all of the forms or #2 disable navigation in the form with the mouse

  Option #1 is less work than redeveloping but look at how much work we've already put into it.

  Option #2 your users will HATE you and come after you with pitch forks and torches. They will perceive that they've got nothing of value for all the work you put into it. Then you will end up doing Option #1 anyway.
- Sometimes a UI that works fine in (or is required by the limitations of) a CUI is just plain wrong and breaks the UI metaphor that users are used to working with in the rest of the GUI (e.g., a pop-up window with list that you have to select an entry in rather than pull down where you can just pick the right value directly)
- When converted to a GUI the CUI may end up with different fonts, text sizes and other formatting defaults than a freshly written form (it did for me). So now either the whole set of forms has to be updated to follow Oracle's new default theme for forms/reports or every new form/report has to reverted back to the old clunky style you had before - or it will stick out like a sore thumb (and your users will want them all to be like the pretty one now).

Not the answer you wanted; huh. But you can use this as an excuse to get out of the Forms/Reports upgrade tread mill and maybe even clean up some of the hacks that have had to happen over the years.