# Character Based Reporting in Birt

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, birt

I had given the task on Character Based Reporting.. I am using BIRT along with JSF and Hibernate for my Project.
Can Anyone tell me what 'Character Based Reporting' is? I had googled the term aswell but the result was bogus.

And does BIRT supports Character Based Reporting or its just Text Based Reporting Engine??

I really Appreciate for your replies and comments

Regards
Wahaj

Comment: The best (and logical) thing to do is to ask the person who gave you the task what "Character Based Reporting" is supposed to be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose text is character based only. There is no term like character based reporting. There are terms like localized reports and all not Character based. Can you elaborate your problem domain a little more wider?

There are character mode reports. Please have a look at this

http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/127921/2/

I have also found this link

[Migrating a Character Based Oracle Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205304/migrating-a-character-based-oracle-form)

Ben

Comment: thanks for the comment, well the scenario is that the client have line matrix printer and from the birt viewer the webpage he sends the document directly to the printer.. and the web page sends the document in an image form.. the line printer prints the document fine when the page consist of text.. but when an image is sent (the document) it take time more then expected for printing.. I have to enhance the engine so that the text is been sent rather an image.. i hope you understand my scenario.. And pardon me for my English..

Comment: PDF is mostly sent as an image to printer. I highly suspect in that case birt has something to do with it. You would be needing some kind of OCR software that can first scan your file and extract all text from that pdf file and make a word document out of it may be and send that text to printer. But this is not what you want. Why are you using such an old printer? Why not try to upgrade the printer?

Comment: Can you check one option on your printer. When you say print, there is an option advanced. There check is this option print pdf as image is checked or not? Try changing PRINT as FILE and play with other options, that might solve your problem.Ben